# How to upload file to S3 without AWS JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest

AWS SDK for `JavaScript` (even if only the `S3` component is included) is a huge bulk for just some sporadic file uploads in my webapp. Is there a leaner way to upload files to an S3 bucket directly from the client's browser, given that I have the bucket name, `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey` at my disposal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 supports uploads from the browser using a form post upload, with no special code needed at the browser.  It involves a specific design of form and a signed policy document that allows the user to only upload files matching constraints you impose, and doesn't expose your secret key.  It will optionally also redirect the browser back to your site after the upload.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

Answer (score 6):

To upload files from browser to S3 you can use presigned PUT. This way you will not be disclosing the aws secret to the browser. You can use the [minio-js](https://github.com/minio/minio-js) library to generate presigned PUT url.

On the server side you can generate the presigned PUT url like this:

```
var Minio = require('minio')

// find out your s3 end point here:
// http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

var s3Client = new Minio({
    url: 'https://<your-s3-endpoint>',
    accessKey: 'YOUR-ACCESSKEYID',
    secretKey: 'YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY'
})
var presignedUrl = s3Client.presignedPutObject('bucket', 'object', 24*60*60)
// presignedUrl expires in 1 day
```

You can pass this presigned URL to the browser which can just do a simple HTTP PUT to amazon s3. The PUT request will succeed because the signature will be part of the presignedUrl.

You can also alternatively use presigned POST to upload too. Presigned POST gives much more control on the upload - like you can limit the size of the upload object, its content-type etc.

Comment: Just a note, if you have the AWS SDK readily available, there's built in stuff for that as well :) `var s3 = new AWS.S3(...); s3.getSignedUrl("putObject", {Bucket: "...", Key: "...", Expires: 60, ContentType: myContentType})`

Answer (score -2):

Try use [Extended S3 Browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extended-s3-browser/ddmmmnnbkhpkgnkafpflhaoohifpdkmg) (Chrome extension)

Comment: You might have been mislead by the word `browser` in my question (i removed it now) — what i meant is uploading a file from a web-app. Chrome extension surely is out of question.